How to create a modular invocable apex action for getting picklist label in flow
I want to get a picklist label value in a flow and I know it’s possible with SOQL but instead thinking of having a modular apex class that can be invoked in a flow with input for the Sobject type, picklist field and value so it avoids a dml and returns the picklist label back to flow

Just write an InvocableMethod that accepts a list of Input, which itself is a wrapper class with the object name, fields name, and picklist value. Then you can describe the object, then the field, then loop to find the Pickard value. The return value can just be the label. Keep in mind that IncocableMethod can run in bulk, so make sure you return one result for every input. See the InvocableMethod Annotation for more information.

Edit:
Sample code that could be used to implement this requirement:
public class GetPicklistValue {
    public class Input {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true label='Object Name') public String objectName;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true label='Field Name') public String fieldName;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true label='Value') public String value;
    }
    public class Output {
        @InvocableVariable public String label;
    }
    @InvocableMethod(Label='Get Picklist Value' description='Gets the label for a picklist value') 
    public static Output[] getPicklistValues(Input[] inputs) {
        // Data to return to the flow
        Output[] results = new Output[0];
        // Intermediate storage for describes and values
        Map<String, Map<String, sObjectField>> fieldMap = new Map<String, Map<String, sObjectField>>();
        Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> neededValues = new Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>>();
        Map<sObjectField, Map<String, String>> valuesToLabels = new Map<sObjectField, Map<String, String>>();

        // Get the object names
        String[] objectNames = new String[0];
        for(Input theInput: inputs) {
            objectNames.add(theInput.objectName);
        }
        // Efficiently deduplicate object names
        objectNames = new List<String>(new Set<String>(objectNames));
        // Describe the objects
        DescribesObjectResult[] describes = Schema.describeSObjects(objectNames, SObjectDescribeOptions.DEFERRED);
        // Initialize the data to find the fields and values we want
        while(objectNames.size() > 0) {
            String objectName = objectNames.remove(0);
            fieldMap.put(objectName, describes.remove(0).fields.getMap());
            neededValues.put(objectName, new Map<String, Set<String>>());
        }
        // Identify the fields and values we want to look through
        for(Input theInput: inputs) {
            Map<String, Set<String>> objectNeededValues = neededValues.get(theInput.objectName);
            Set<String> fieldNeededValues = objectNeededValues.get(theInput.fieldName);
            if(fieldNeededValues == null) {
                objectNeededValues.put(theInput.fieldName, fieldNeededValues = new Set<String>());
            }
            fieldNeededValues.addAll((theInput.value).split(';')); // could be multiple values so split by ;
        }
        // Nested for loops like this are not a bad practice
        // For each Object
        for(String objectName: neededValues.keySet()) {
            Map<String, Set<String>> objectNeededValues = neededValues.get(objectName);
            Map<String, sObjectField> objectFields = fieldMap.get(objectName);
            // For each field
            for(String fieldName: objectNeededValues.keySet()) {
                Set<String> fieldNeededValues = objectNeededValues.get(fieldName);
                sObjectField field = objectFields.get(fieldName);
                Map<String, String> fieldValuesToLabels = new Map<String, String>();
                valuesToLabels.put(field, fieldValuesToLabels);
                // Read each picklist value
                for(PicklistEntry entry: field.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()) {
                    // Remove returns true if the set was modified
                    if(fieldNeededValues.remove(entry.value)) {
                        fieldValuesToLabels.put(entry.value, entry.label);
                    }
                    // We can break early if we found all the values
                    if(fieldNeededValues.isEmpty()) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Finally, we can get the label for each value
        for(Input theInput: inputs) {
            Output result = new Output();
            result.label = valuesToLabels.get(fieldMap.get(theInput.objectName).get(theInput.fieldName))
                .values().toString().replace(', ',';').replace('(','').replace(')','') ?? '<not found>'; // adjusted to get all the values and format as semi-colon seperated
            results.add(result);
        }
        return results;
    }
}


Sorry... I'm mobile right now. I'll try to add code later.

I've submitted an edit to sfdcfox's sample (great answer thankyou!) to have it work with multi-pick list values and return a ; seperated list when there are multiple values.
Frustratingly couldnt just put this as a comment as not enough reputation...
If anyone needs the two changes are:
#42 fieldNeededValues.addAll((theInput.value).split(';')); // could be multiple values so split by ;
#72 result.label = valuesToLabels.get(fieldMap.get(theInput.objectName).get(theInput.fieldName))
            .values().toString().replace(', ',';').replace('(','').replace(')','') ?? '<not found>'; // adjusted to get all the values and format as comma seperated

